# Could not clone a GitLab repository using subprocess

Tags: python, git, gitlab, subprocess, clone

I need to clone a GitLab repository using subprocess, here's my code:

```
import subprocess

gitlab_repo_url = "https://gitlab.int.my.company./namespace/project-name.git"
destination_folder = "/c/Users/username/Documents/destination-folder"

subprocess.run(["git", "clone", gitlab_repo_url, destination_folder])
```

But the clone process can not be complete when running the script while I can use the gitlab_repo_url to clone the repo to the destination_folder on a terminal successfully.

I got this result when executing the script:

```
Cloning into '/c/Users/username/Documents/destination-folder'...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Means the execution has finished. But when I go to that destination folder, it's empty. If I then re-run this script, I will get this result:

```
fatal: destination path '/c/Users/username/Documents/destination-folder' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But the folder is actually empty. If I run 'ls -a' in this folder on a terminal, I will get './  ../'

Any ideas will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Since this is a “company” repo I’m guessing that it isn’t publicly available. Don’t you need to pass some credentials to the subprocess?

Comment: does `git clone` in command prompt succeed? (`destination_folder` is not empty?)

Comment: Hi @rok, yes git clone works well in a terminal.

Comment: Hi @Guildenstern, yes repo is not public. But it should not be something with the credentials as I found I can actually clone it - but only to the same parent directory with this script. So the issue turned to that I can clone it but can not clone it to any other folder.

Comment: is the repository empty?